# How do I get a website switcher instead of store switcher?

Tags: templates, layout, web, magento, switching

How do I create a dropdown menu for switching websites and not just stores?

More specifically, I want to switch between Magento websites. There's a dropdown menu in a template for switching stores and one for switching languages, but there isn't one for switching websites.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a solution on the Magento forums: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8296/

You have to create a copy of the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/stores.phtml` template in your custom theme package.

Then you have to modify it to use the following code:

```
<?php
$websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();

if (count($websites) > 1): ?>
<div class="website-switcher">
    <label for="select-website"><?php echo $this->__('Select Store:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-website" title="<?php echo $this->__('Select Store') ?>" onchange="location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($websites as $website): // print out each website name and code as a dropdown box item ?>
        <?php $_selected = $website->getCode() == Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getCode() ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $website->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl()?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($website->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Links to Magento API docs for the methods used:

- [Mage::app()->getWebsites()](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Model_App.html#getWebsites)
- [Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getCode()](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Model_Website.html#getCode)
- [$website->getCode()](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Model_Website.html#getCode)
- [$website->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl()](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Model_Store.html#getBaseUrl)